# Why stack iterator works in reverse order?

Tags: java, iterator, stack

I was trying to iterate over stack using iterator by:

```
Iterator it = stack.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.print(it.next()+"\t");
```

I just have noticed that it is iterating in reverse order. Is it because iterator always points the start of a collection (for this case iterator is pointing the stating of the vector).

*N.B: 
I know below code will give proper output for stack operation. I am curious about the iterator behavior.*

```
Iterator it2 = stack.iterator();
while(it2.hasNext())
    System.out.print(stack.pop()+"\t");
```

Comment: why do you think that starting at the beginning is the *reverse* order?

Comment: I initialized the stack by:
        `for(int i = 1; i<= 10; i++)
            stack.push(i);`
and the first iteration output as: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
although the expected stack result is: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: Because a `Stack` is a LIFO data structure. It's also important to note that the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) javadoc explicitly says *Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy `Stack` class.*

Comment: @ScaryWombat: I believe by asking _Is it because iterator always points the start of a collection (for this case iterator is pointing the stating of the vector)_ I have expressed what I was confused with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `iterator` method in [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is inherited from, not overridden in `Vector`, which would simply iterate through its elements in insert order.  This is contrast to the order in which elements would be popped off of a stack.  This is just normal `Iterator` behavior in `Vector`, which has nothing to do with `Stack`.

If you would like a more fully-functional `Stack`, use an implementation of the `Deque` interface, e.g. `ArrayDeque`.  It implements stack and queue functionality at the same time.  Because it [`push`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#push-E-)es elements to the *front* of the `Deque`, the iterator, which processes elements from front to back, will give elements in the order that they would be popped from the stack.

> Pushes an element onto the stack represented by this deque (in other words, at the head of this deque)